# Python Array Column Match in a CSV File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am looking for a python 3 example,

I need to open a csv file, look at a certain column in the CSV file, create a new column from those values in a new csv file, 
and change some values in the new column based on a match from a list.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The module documentation of **csv-module** has examples, go and read the API for [module csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and something about [file open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and about other needed stuff: [built.ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions). Code your solution, test it and if it breaks, come back with a _specific question_ and your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, your question is too broad.

Comment: Or use http://pandas.pydata.org/